# Multiplying by sizeof(char) is different than just the multiplying by the size of a char

Tags: c, sizeof

I have been having some odd problems as of late with some code that I have written.

```
printf("%li\n",(sizeof(char)));
printf("%li\n",sizeof(4*(sizeof(char))));
```

When I run the code the first line prints "1" and the second prints "8".  If I were to multiply 4 by 1 I would get four. Why is this happening?

Comment: Curious: Why did you code format specifier `"%li\"` with `sizeof(char))`?

Comment: Format specifier for a `size_t` (type of he result of `sizeof`) is `"%zu"`!

Comment: The correct C99/C11 [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) length modifier for `size_t` is `z`, as in `%zu`.  Which is what @chux was driving towards — you should be using `%zu` or something similar rather than `%li` which is not guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: I incorrectly thought that size of() returned a long int. This was reinforced when it did not throw any warnings or errors.  I should have used %zu.

Comment: `printf` format missmatch warnings are not enforced by the standard, as they are actually run-time errors. However, modern compilers like gcc and clang actually should warn if you enable recommended warnings. However, you should always make very sure, as using an incorrect format specifier invokes undefined behaviour. Do not rely on warnings.

Comment: Also note that a format that generates no warning on a 64-bit platform may generate a warning on a 32-bit platform and vice versa since the compiler looks at 'equivalent formats' from its current perspective (one machine, one bittiness), not from viewpoint of the general portability of source code.

Comment: @OP, thanks for the "I incorrectly thought that size of() returned a long int."  I was truly trying to understand why folks choose various format specifiers for `sizeof()` instead of correct/portable ones like `"%zu"` `"%zo"`, `"%zx"`, `"%zX"`.  Was `long int` something you read or was advised by others?

Comment: I read it in someones code somewhere, but that was a while ago and I no longer know where.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I agree, but FWIW: On Linux 64 (LP64) gcc reports `warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long long int’` for `printf("%ld", 1LL);` actually. Both have the same representation/layout.

Comment: @chux: Because there are broken compiler-hawkers which are not even able to update their libraries (format-string parser; it is not even a compiler-issue) within >16 years.

Comment: @chux one popular C and C++ implementation does not support `%zu`, which is why these shenanigans exist

Comment: @Matt McNabb A standard work-around when printing an unsigned integer of unknown width is to cast to the widest type that `printf()` is known to support such as `printf("%llu", (unsigned long long) sizeof(x))`. (I suspect you know this - left here as a comment for others too.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you meant to print `4*(sizeof(char))`. That would have given `4`.

However you actually printed `sizeof(4*(sizeof(char)))` .  `sizeof` yields the number of bytes required to store its operand.

The type of `4*sizeof(char)` is `size_t` which is a 64-bit type on your system, so you are getting `8` as the output.

You would get the same result by printing `sizeof(123456*sizeof(float))`.  `sizeof` does not tell you anything about the value of its operand, just how many bytes are required to store it.

Answer (score 0):

`4*sizeof(char)` is 4, but it's a `size_t` (typically the same size as `long`).  Its size is 8 on your 64-bit machine.

Comment: Since the result of `sizeof(char)` is a `size_t` value, `4 * sizeof(char)` is also a `size_t` and `sizeof(4 * sizeof(char))` is the size of a `size_t`, which is 8 on a 64-bit machine.  So, my objection is to the appearance of `int` in your answer, not least because on all 64-bit machines I know of in current use, `sizeof(int)` is 4 (32-bits) and not 8.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Didn't the the Alpha use ILP64  (64 bit `int`/`long` _pointer_)? IIRC, there are still some in use and at least the early versions only had word-load/store. (I might be wrong, however - long time ago).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'm currently browsing, perhaps you are faster to find evidence: http://h18002.www1.hp.com/alphaserver/technology/chip-docs.html

Comment: @Olaf: The DEC Alpha was a platform where I think it was originally ILP64 (int, long, pointers all 64-bit) rather than the more modern  LP64 (long and pointer 64-bit; int 32-bit by inference) recommended by POSIX or X/Open. However, when I've raised that memory elsewhere on SO, it has been discounted, and I've not found documentary evidence for the ILP64 state, or for a change from ILP64 to LP64. Back in 1994±1, I got an early Alpha to work on, and I'm almost sure that it was ILP64 — and I infer from your comment that you have similar memories. DEC Alpha was why I added 'in current use'.

Comment: However, the current incarnations of DEC (Compaq, HP) Alpha are LP64, that is clear from various sources, and I've not found definitive evidence of DEC Alpha running ILP64, so I have to assume either that I am misremembering the status quo circa 1995 or that I misunderstood it at the time.  (But it's odd; I think I remember having to do some coding around `int` being 64-bit on DEC Alpha.  I'd have to delve back through some archaic code bases to prove that, though.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: If you do, there are actually two to missremember (and possibly for similar reasons). Back then, I followed such development only out of interest. sadly I never got my fingers at such irons (not that I would have had any idea how to program or even operate such beasts;-). I was happy to login to our HP-UX pool and run xbattle (that reminds me .. I really should try find it and make it run on my desktop).

Comment: `4*sizeof(char)` has the value of 4, and type `size_t`, not `int`.

Comment: I've found what looks to be a good summary of the issues in [The long road to 64 bits](https://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1165766) from 2006 by John Mashey, and it clearly states that DEC was using LP64 from the beginning, so I have to assume I was mistaken.  Until I get into software archaeology...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Well, I found this [document](http://h18002.www1.hp.com/cpq-alphaserver/technology/literature/cmpwrgd.pdf) which states (page 1-3, section 1.2) that it did support 32 and 64 bit loads only (supporting at least my claim about the `char` handling penalties), so LP64 would be well possible. Sorry I could not help you.

Comment: @ {olafgf, jonathan} : dec alpha had sizeof int() ==4, sizeof(long) ==8. Linus used these in the initial Alpha port (silly "Jensen"), only to be able to use the "bootstrap" DEC binaries. Afterwards, the type system evolved. (this was around christmas 1994, IIRC)